# react useEffect is not running

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

my useEffect was working, but now it isn't.  I have no idea why.  console.log show nothing is getting executed on initial run now.  Code is below.  Its pretty simple code, i was just getting started with functional components.  When InvTable is called, i'm getting a null error inside it because tablesCopy is undefined obviously.

```
const App = () => {
  const [tablesOrig, setTablesOrig] = useState<any>({});
  const [tablesCopy, setTablesCopy] = useState<any>({});
  const [numOfTables, setNumOfTables] = useState<number>(-1);
  const [rowTarget, setRowTarget] = useState<string>("");

  const setEditRow = (e: React.BaseSyntheticEvent) => {
    setRowTarget(e.target.id);
    console.log("setEditRow -> rowTarget", rowTarget);
  };

   
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const path = "/tables.json";
      console.log("fetchData -> path", path);  // <- never executes
      const response = await fetch(path);
      const tables: any = await response.json();
      setTablesOrig(tables);
      setTablesCopy({ ...tables });
      const tableKeys = Object.keys(tablesCopy);
      setNumOfTables(tableKeys.length);

    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

    
  return (
    <>
      <InvTable table={tablesCopy[0]} tableId={0} setEditRow={setEditRow} />
    </>
  );
};;
```

Comment: Well it's probably that null error. That's gonna throw an error, which is gonna halt execution, which means it doesn't continue onto the effect which runs *after* everything is mounted. Fix your `tablesCopy` error and see if effect runs

Comment: ah @Jayce444 InvTable gets invoked once before useEffect eventually gets called?

Comment: Well the effect without deps is the same as `componentDidMount`, so the effect runs **after** the component mounts. The rendering of what you return is considered part of mounting, so it will render the `InvTable`, and only stuff is rendered is mounting considered done, and the effect called

Comment: you'll need to add `await` before `fetchData()` at the end, it's an async function, it is not guaranteed to run in the same processor tick.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar and await what? `fetchData` doesn't return anything and there is no further code after the call in the effect, and `useEffect` hook callbacks ***can't*** be `async` so they can't `await` anything.

Comment: that's fine, just `await fetchData()` don't bother about the returned value at all

Comment: Is `table={tablesCopy[0]}` definitely valid? I see you expect this to be an object according to the useState value. Is `0` an expected key of that object? Just checking that you're not expecting it to be an array when it is actually an object

Comment: @Ibz, yes its def valid, its not going to be the end result, i'm just propping up some data at this point

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar, i didn't need await before when this was working, also async would have to be on useEffect as well correct?

Comment: @Jayce444, if i put in a table check inside InvTable, it'll render as expected on 2nd sweep after calling useEffect.  I'll monitor this for awhile if you want to move your comment to an answer and I can give the karma.  thanks for help.

Comment: @PompeyMagnus yes, that would be required `useEffect( async () => { } )` might work.